# Refresh UIDatePicker disabled dates color

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

## Description

I have `UIDatePicker` with `datePickerMode` set to `date`, `minimumDate` and `maximumDate` are also set. Dates that are after `maximumDate` are disabled and with different color to indicate that they cannot be selected.

**Code for `UIDatePicker`**

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.minimumDate = Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
datePicker.maximumDate = Date()
datePicker.setValue(UIColor.yellow, forKeyPath: "textColor")
datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
```

**Disabled future dates**

[image: Disabled dates in future]

When year is changed to year in the past it's expected that month and date are refreshed and color is changed, which is not the case.

[image: Date in past but month and day disabled]

Notice how 2018 has yellow color indicating that it can be selected but August and 26 do not have that color like they are not selectable. But when I scroll to them they will change color to yellow since year is 2017.

## Question

How to refresh disabled date picker components when date picker changes value?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is switching *datePickerMode* to another and switching it back. It works but breaks picker animations :/

```
@IBAction private func datePickerChangedAction(_ sender: Any) {
    self.datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
    self.datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    // ...
}
```